# MPChart IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

Using MPCharts to plot LineChart in Android, its throwing `"IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25"`. Gone through the examples but still getting the same error. Find the below code

```
 private void drawLineChart() {

    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    System.out.println("valueList"+valueList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i <= valueList.size(); i++){

        entries.add(new Entry(valueList.get(i),(float)i));

    }

    LineChart lineChart = findViewById(R.id.myLineChart);
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText("My Line Chart");
    lineChart.setDescription(description);

    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line chart");
    lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
    lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    lineData.setValueFormatter(new ReportChartXAxisValueFormater(getXAxisValues()));

    lineChart.setData(lineData);
    lineChart.animateXY(2000,2000);
    lineChart.invalidate();

}
```

ValueList has 25 values

Comment: you have `for (int i = 0; i <= valueList.size(); i++){` 
should be `for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++){`

Change `<=` to `<`

Comment: Before posting it, you could have searched on google, it is common problem

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Change your condition from (lower or equal)

```
i <= valueList.size()
```

to (lower):

```
i < valueList.size()
```

### Correct code:

```
//      change char here (from <=  to  < )
//                ||
//                \/
for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++){
    // your code there
}
```

You have `25` elements. Size of the list is `25`.

But indexes are from `0` to `24`.

### Example:

Indexing start from 0.

So for `5` elements you have such positions:

```
element:   "ABC",     "DEF",     "GHI",     "JKL",     "MNO",  
position:    0          1          2          3          4
```

Size is `5` (because you have `5` elements).

But last last index is `4`. That is the reason why your iterator can NOT reach size of the list.

Comment: Added explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
for (int i = 0; i <= valueList.size(); i++)
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++)
```

Java indices start at `0` and end at `size()-1`, so the `get()` call will throw the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you use `size()`, which is 25 in this case.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the number of values in the list are still `25`, but the indexing begins with `0`, so the last index is `24`. You do NOT need to make any other changes than the one mentioned in our answers, which is to replace `<=` with `<` in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Index start from zero and end at size-1

```
for (int i = 0; i <= valueList.size(); i++){...
```

You are using `<=` which will also include last index that won't be there thus the exception. Replace `<=` with `<` or use `size()-1`

Comment: you actually are passing 25 values, its the index that starts with 0 and end at (25-1) so to access 25th element you need to use 24 index.